# Show the series defines an infinitely differentiable function

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, derivatives

> show $f(x) = \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(x+n)}$ defined on $[0, \infty)$ is $C^\infty$

I'm working on this practice problem.  I differentiated each term to get

$$g(x) = \sum \frac{d}{dx} \frac{1}{n(x+n)}=\sum \frac{-1}{nx^2+2xn^2+n^3} = \frac{d}{dx} \sum  \frac{1}{n(x+n)}=f'(x)$$

interchanging the differentiation and the sum becasue the sum of the derivatives converges uniformly on the domain.

Then I continued by induction, using the fact that the order of the numerator of $g$ is 3 less than the order of the denominator, to say that if we keep taking the derivative we will keep getting uniformly convergent series and can interchange the differentiation and the sum.

This seems messy to me - I'm not sure it works 100%.  Am I missing something?  Or is there a cleaner way to do this problem like transform it into a power series?

Comment: Your overall argument is a good one. You also need induction. You can streamline things by writing down an infinite series for each derivative, since $\frac{d^k}{dx^k} (x+n)^{-1}= (-1)^k (k-1)! (x+n)^{-1-k}$.